# how to use whereClause, whereArgs when updating a table in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application i have tried to update a table using

> sqliteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(table, values, whereClause, whereClause, conflictAlgorithm)

method but i have no clear idea about whereClause and whereClause variables.following code will not give any exception or error but the table will not be updated.

```
AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelper = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(CreateListsActivity.this);
                                    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                                    values.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.LIST_NAME, editedKeyword);

                                    sqliteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LISTS, values, AndroidOpenDbHelper.LIST_NAME + "=" + id,null, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                                    sqliteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_KEYWORDS, values, AndroidOpenDbHelper.LIST_NAME + "=" + id, null, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                                    sqliteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_TWEET, values, AndroidOpenDbHelper.LIST_NAME + "=" + id, null, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

                                    sqliteDatabase.close();
```

any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

Your conflict algorithm is IGNORE -
"When a constraint violation occurs, the one row that contains the constraint violation is not inserted or changed"

Does AndroidOpenDbHelper.LIST_NAME have a unique constraint on it which you may be violating? Try FAIL and check the return code:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_FAIL

Also, bind the parameters in the statement. Thats the correct way to use where clause and args -

```
sqliteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_KEYWORDS, values, AndroidOpenDbHelper.LIST_NAME + "= ?" , new String[]{id}, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Comment: my id is long value i have to cast it to String to put as new String[]{id}. is it ok?

Comment: String.valueOf(yourlongId) would be better.

Answer (score -3):

you can write your own sql update statement like this:

```
String sql="update <tableName> set <columnName> = 'newValue' where <columnName>= 'oldValue' ";
sqliteDatabase.execSql(sql,null);
```