# Android SQLite -- What is the logic behind using whereArgs

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Considering `whereArgs` in functions like:

```
mDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, values, whereClause, whereArgs)
```

I know it is used for "?"s in `whereClause`, but I have no idea why to invent this `whereArgs` instead of inserting the args into `whereClause` directly. Did not find any convenience by extracting the "?"s from `whereClause` to `whereArgs`. Could anyone give a good example that shows how useful is `whereArgs`? Appreciate it!

Comment: a simple reason is to prevent **SQL injection**

Comment: @SMR there are other ways to prevent SQL injection, so this doesn't answer the question by itself (although maybe that's why you made it a comment and not an answer)

Comment: @immibis if you know the exact reason the you are welcome to answer. :)

Comment: About how to use whereArgs take a look on related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631947/how-to-use-whereclause-whereargs-when-updating-a-table-in-sqlite and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373380/whereargs-sqlite-database-delete.

Comment: @SMR Yah, should be a reason. I'm new in SQL and a bit misled by Android's reference -- "Convenience method for...". Didn't think it can be security reason.

Comment: @SMR When checking SQL injection, I also found it is called [**Prepared statement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). It states there is another advantage of increasing the efficiency of repeated similar statements. But I guess that's not the case in using Android functions like delete, insert, etc. right?

Comment: @immibis lol, seems I can only @ one person at a time. Would you mind have a check on above comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29), it's used for `?` markers in your query string. For example, you might use this:

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete("users", "user_name = ?", new String[] {"Talib"});
```

The use of parameter markers is very important for avoiding [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For example,

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete("users", "user_name = ?", new String[] {"' OR '' = '"});
```

will not delete all rows of your table, but if you naively did

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete("users", "user_name = '" + userName + "'");
```

and `userName` was set to `"' OR '' = '"`, that would indeed nuke your whole table.

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304490/1239966

Comment: Yah, correct. Didn't think about security reason. Thanks! When checking SQL injection, I also found it is called [**Prepared statement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). It states there is another advantage of increasing the efficiency of repeated similar statements. But I guess that's not the case in using Android functions like delete, insert, etc. right?

Comment: Thanks Shivam! Found it could be useful when using "transaction". https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Working+with+a+SQLite+Database#WorkingwithaSQLiteDatabase-Usetransactionstospeedbatchinserts